# err = new ServerSelectionError();

Tags: mongodb

Server started on port 3000
C:\Users\Vishal Kumar\Desktop\webdevelopment\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:755
err = new ServerSelectionError();
^

MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 1
at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\Vishal Kumar\Desktop\webdevelopment\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:755:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\Vishal Kumar\Desktop\webdevelopment\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:730:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) {
'1:27017' => ServerDescription {
address: '1:27017',
type: 'Unknown',
hosts: [],
passives: [],
arbiters: [],
tags: {},
minWireVersion: 0,
maxWireVersion: 0,
roundTripTime: -1,
lastUpdateTime: 360536860,
lastWriteDate: 0,
error: MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 1
at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\Vishal Kumar\Desktop\webdevelopment\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:383:20)
at Socket. (C:\Users\Vishal Kumar\Desktop\webdevelopment\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:307:22)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 1
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
errno: -3008,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: '1'
},
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
},
topologyVersion: null,
setName: null,
setVersion: null,
electionId: null,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
primary: null,
me: null,
'$clusterTime': null
}
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
}
how can  i solve it
???

How can i resolve it.

Comment: That looks like a bad connection string, what code is throwing that error?